# Stringbuilder is escaping HTML symbols

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that's building a drop down list based on what's sent from the model.

```
@{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<select id=\"field"+Model.Id+"\">");
sb.Append("<option>Choose...</option>");
foreach(var s in Model.Choices)
{
    sb.Append("<option>" + s + "</option>");
}
sb.Append("</select>");
var str = sb.ToString();
}

$("#label" + "@Model.Id").html("@str");
```

But in the browser, instead of it creating a drop down list, it's actually outputting the entire string `"<select id="field3"><option>Choose...</option><option>Movie</option><option>TV Show</option><option>Shorts</option></select>"`

Why is it doing this and how can I get it to show the actual drop down list?

Comment: Oh sure, blame the StringBuilder.

Comment: You could also create a select list from the Model.Choices and use the Html.DropDownList helper. Let me know if you need code.

Comment: As a side note - you might want to check whether `s` and `Model.Id` need to be encoded. Unless they are integers, they probably should be - otherwise you risk client-side injection (XSS etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you need is HtmlString.

```
@{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<select id=\"field"+Model.Id+"\">");
sb.Append("<option>Choose...</option>");
foreach(var s in Model.Choices)
{
    sb.Append("<option>" + s + "</option>");
}
sb.Append("</select>");
var str = new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Strings are now automatically Html encoded if they are plain strings but an HtmlString object is rendered as is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.